# GoJS not stretching shapes to fit parent

Tags: javascript, gojs

I was trying to make a title shape inside a Panel, which is again inside of a Node.
My code as far looks like that:

```
var _ = go.GraphObject.make;
var template =
_(go.Node, "Spot",{
    minSize: new go.Size(150, NaN)
    }
    _(go.Panel, go.Panel.Auto,
        _(go.Shape, {
                    figure: "Rectangle",
                    fill: "#ff00ff",
                    stroke: "#000000",
                    strokeWidth: 1,                
                    alignment: new go.Spot(0.5, 0) //aligning it center
            }
        )
    )
);
```

If i want to stretch the element as far as i want i would add

```
stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill
```

Or (if horizontally)

```
stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal
```

But the Shape does **not** stretch horizontally.

What i have also tried until now:

- Adding a defaultStretch to the Panel
- Adding a defaultStretch to the Node and the Panel
- Changing the Panels layout (or positioning if you want so)
- Changing the Nodes layout (or positioning)
- setting minSize or maxSize in both dimensions on every of the three Components

I did research it on the Gojs website, but was only able to find the things mentioned above.

Thank you for helping me

*PS: if any additional info is needed, i will be happy to provide it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases a Panel should have more than one element in it.  In your code you actually have two Panels, each of which has only one element in it.  And your code doesn't show any text (there's no TextBlock), so it cannot act as a title.

You haven't said which element it was that you wanted to stretch.  Setting GraphObject.stretch is the right thing to do.  But sometimes you need to also set it on a Panel, to make sure the Panel is stretched to allow what is inside the panel to be stretched as well.

Panel.defaultStretch is just a way of setting the default value of GraphObject.stretch on each of the elements of the panel.

My guess is that you want to use an "Auto" Panel if you want to have a Shape that is stretched to fit around another object (possibly a TextBlock).  This is what you see by default in the Minimal sample as well as many other samples.

If you add:
        { minSize: new go.Size(150, NaN) },
to the Node template in the Minimal sample, you'll see:
[image: Minimal sample with minSize Nodes]

Is that what you were looking for?  If not, please add a sketch of what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed it myself in the meantime, doing mainly what you suggested in your answer. But one thing needs to be done that the stretch can take affect: setting the width of something.  In my case i had a Node with two panels (one for Shapes, one for Texts).  I allways defined something like stretch:... fill or Text.wrapfit,but i never stated what to do if there was practically no content.  minSize: didn't work here. i had to set minSize, plus i had to set a desired **width** on the Node, then everything worked out fine.

Comment: Yes, if you want text to wrap the allowed width must be limited. You can do that by setting the width (a.k.a.desiredSize.width), by setting the maxSize.width, or by having the panel restrict its actual width. If you set the width to a real number you don't need to set the minSize or maxSize. http://gojs.net/latest/intro/sizing.html

Comment: Well, the Problem here was, even if i had set a minSize (panel, or node, or both) the stretch would not work as there was no desired width set.  
so now i have a code like this: minSize: new go.Size(150, NaN), width: 150. In my case the width gets overwritten quite often as i use long titles which determine the size (in my case)